# How to use Rapier in TypeScript with ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rapier

The [Rapier physics engine](https://rapier.rs) written in Rust is exposed to JavaScript by loading the library into a module dynamically. From [Getting started](https://rapier.rs/docs/user_guides/javascript/getting_started_js):

> ```
> import('@dimforge/rapier2d').then(RAPIER => {
>     ...
> });
> ```

I need to use the Rapier module to instantiate vectors from outside code from TypeScript and Node.js with `ts-node`. I'm not sure if the properties matter much since it's all dynamically-typed and TypeScript does structural type checks also, but when invoking `new rapier.Vector` it could matter.

I created a convenient layer over Rapier's JavaScript bindings (`com.hydroper.matter`) which uses this internally, leaving their dynamic module at the static lifetime of the JavaScript program:

```
import * as rapierTypings from "@dimforge/rapier2d/rapier";
import Vector from "../math/Vector";
import { RigidBodyType } from "../RigidBody";

const Rapier = {
    rapier: undefined as (typeof import("@dimforge/rapier2d/rapier") | undefined),

    get(): typeof import("@dimforge/rapier2d/rapier") {
        if (Rapier.rapier === undefined) {
            throw new Error("com.hydroper.matter must be preloaded before use; do so through the asynchronous load() method.");
        }
        return Rapier.rapier;
    },

    ...
};
```

Now... `ts-node` is reporting the following issue when I run my terminal application that uses Rapier indirectly:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@dimforge/rapier2d'
Require stack:
- /fooProject/matter/ts/index.ts
- /fooProject/fooProject-server/ts/car/Car.ts
- /fooProject/fooProject-server/ts/Peer.ts
- /fooProject/fooProject-server/ts/index.ts
- /fooProject/fooProject-server/bin/fooProject-server
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/fooProject/fooProject-server/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at /fooProject/matter/ts/index.ts:47:21 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/fooProject/matter/ts/index.ts',
    '/fooProject/fooProject-server/ts/car/Car.ts',
    '/fooProject/fooProject-server/ts/Peer.ts',
    '/fooProject/fooProject-server/ts/index.ts',
    '/fooProject/fooProject-server/bin/fooProject-server'
  ]
}
```

Relevant code from `index.ts`:

```
export async function load(): Promise<void> {
    if (Rapier.rapier !== undefined) {
        return;
    }
    Rapier.rapier = await import("@dimforge/rapier2d");
}
```

The error is on this import specifically.